# How many times is the array copied in this piece of code?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy

A minimum working example:

```
#include <string.h>

struct pair_t;

class A {
    public:
        A(const char *s) { strcpy(buf, s); }
        struct pair_t dup();
    private:
        char buf[32];
};

struct pair_t {
    A left;
    A right;
};

struct pair_t A::dup() {
    return (struct pair_t){ A(buf), A(buf) };
}

int main() {
    A a1("alpha");    
    pair_t pair = a1.dup();
}
```

In the line `pair_t pair = a1.dup();` as well as inside the call of `A::dup()`, how many times is the `buf` array copied? 2? 4? More?

---

Apparently my question is not as clear as I thought. Let me elaborate. I'm also looking for more of a "what does the standard say it should do" rather than "what does the specific version of the compiler I have installed right now do", so I'd rather not count based on debug statements.

In `A::dup`, I create a struct `pair_t` and fill it with two objects. I call the constructors of these two objects. So that's 2.

Presumably this `pair_t` is local to this function, but it is returned externally to this function. Does this create a copy of `pair_t` to be returned into the `main` function? If so, does it also copy the `left` and `right` inside? And if so, does it copy via the constructors or does it do some sort of behind-the-scenes direct memory copy? How many do these add up to?

Comment: JFME, what is MWE?

Comment: Try adding some tracing to your constructor, and then create a copy- and move-constructors so you can trace those too, *and* a copy- and move-assignment operator. Then it's a simple issue of counting.

Comment: @VadimKey MWE is Minimum Working Example. A term commonly used on Stack Overflow

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is it guaranteed that the copies are always done by the constructor?

Comment: @Ana, there are also copy and move constructors as well as return value optimization. BTW you don't need to specify "struct" in C++ when mention the type.

Comment: If copy-/move-constructors are used, or copy-/move-assignment is depending on the situation and what you are doing, and what other classes you are using. In your case the assignment operators will most likely not be used though.

Answer (score 1):

You can easy test it:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct pair_t;

class A {
public:
  A(const char *s) {
    std::cout << "ctor: " << s << std::endl;
    strcpy(buf, s);
  }

  A(const A& a) {
    std::cout << "copy ctor: " << a.buf << std::endl;
    memcpy(buf, a.buf, sizeof(buf));
  }

  A(A&& a) {
    std::cout << "move ctor" << a.buf << std::endl;
    std::swap(buf, a.buf);
  }

  pair_t dup();
private:
  char buf[32];
};


struct pair_t {
  A left;
  A right;
};


pair_t A::dup() {
  return (struct pair_t){ A(buf), A(buf) };
}

int main() {
  A a1("alpha");
  std::cout << "call dup:" << std::endl;
  pair_t pair = a1.dup();
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
ctor: alpha
call dup:
ctor: alpha
ctor: alpha
```